# URL modification via regex

Tags: regex

Regex makes my head explode. Can you help me with my use case?

I need to be able to modify URL to be of this sort:
m.example.com/etc

Source URL can be anything:

```
www.example1.com/etc
example2.com/etc
example3.net/etc
trial.example4.com/etc
```

The regex would need to only look at the part before /
then only look at what precedes .com or .net or .whatever
when it's an absolute domain it would intro the m.
when there is www. or someprefix. it would be transformed to m.

SO using the sources above, I'd like:

```
m.example1.com/etc
m.example2.com/etc
m.example3.net/etc
m.example4.com/etc
```

Comment: URL is kind of a nasty parse chore. Why not use some module that knows how to do that? Otherwise, I've seen URL regex that exceed 16k bytes or more.

Comment: bad idea to use regex here.

Comment: I have to use regex. No eng resource to code anything else. Doesn't have to be 100% working, I'll take a 99% working solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex you don't have to, while it's a bit longer you can do this with some string methods. Here is a really basic example:

```js
function changeURL(string){
    if( string.split(".").length > 2 ) {
        var firstPart = string.substring(0,string.indexOf("."));
        string = string.replace(firstPart, "m");  
    }
    else{
        string = "m."+string;
    }
    return string; 
}

console.log(changeURL("www.example1.com/etc"));
console.log(changeURL("example2.com/etc"));
console.log(changeURL("example3.net/etc"));
console.log(changeURL("trial.example4.com/etc"));
```

Will all give the correct results. The main problem is we don't know the difference between replacing `example2.com` or `www.example1.com` with `m`, it would be `m.com` (we don't want) and `m.example1.com` (we do want). So what I did was to check if there are at least two or more `.`'s to replace the first substring with `m`, otherwise juse add `m.` to the string. Obviously this will not work for all cases, you can break it easily with `example5.com.net` would give `m.com.net`.

To fix that you will need to identity all the possible items that the URL needs to start with `www`, `trial`, etc, and check for those. But if it's anything, we really cannot solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is your friend

```
(.*)(\.*?\/.*)
```

First group is the one you replace. Second groups is the .com/whatever

```
(.*)(\..{3}\/.*)
```

if you want to make  sure it's a three letter ending

EDIT:
try this:

```
(\..{2,3})*(\/.*)
```

It will not work if the domain is also 2 or 3 characters long. But you said you only needed a mostly-work solution.

I recommend this site:
https://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Comment: The first group doesn't catch what I need and the second group could be an issue with domain from the uk for instance.  www.example.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified regex taken from some other post.
All it does is isolate the first part of the dot portion of the URL,
if more than 2 dots. Don't know if that's what you're looking for or not.

Find:

```
^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?)(?:(?|((?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])\.)((?:(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){2})([1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4])(?!)|((?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+\.)?((?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+\.)+)([a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))|localhost(?!))((?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?)$
```

Replace:  `$1m.$3$4$5`

Input

```
www.example1.com/etc
example2.com/etc
example3.net/etc
trial.example4.com/etc
```

Output

```
m.example1.com/etc
m.example2.com/etc
m.example3.net/etc
m.example4.com/etc
```

Regex

```
 ^ 
 # Device ------------
 (                                                     # (1 start)
      (?! mailto: )
      (?:
           (?: https? | ftp )
           ://
      )?
      (?:
           \S+ 
           (?: : \S* )?
           @
      )?
 )                                                     # (1 end)

 # Address ------------
 (?:
      (?|                                                   # Branch Reset start
           # This part will be failed
           # (left for posterity, remove block if not needed)
           (                                                     # (2 start)
                (?: [1-9] \d? | 1 \d\d | 2 [01] \d | 22 [0-3] )
                \.
           )                                                     # (2 end)
           (                                                     # (3 start)
                (?:
                     (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
                     \.
                ){2}
           )                                                     # (3 end)
           ( [1-9] \d? | 1 \d\d | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-4] )        # (4)

           # Fail this part (remove this to include logic)
           (?!)

        |                                                      # Breset OR,
           # This is the only part we are looking for
           (                                                     # (2 start)
                # Optional, First part (if greater than 2 dots)
                # -----------------------------------
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
                \.
           )?                                                    # (2 end)
           (                                                     # (3 start)
                # First part (if equal 2 dots)
                # Second part (if greater than 2 dots)
                # -----------------------------------
                (?:
                     (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                     [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
                     \.                    
                )+
           )                                                     # (3 end)
           ( [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )                            # (4)
      )                                                     # End of Branch Reset
   |                                                      # or,
      # Fail localhost (left for posterity)
      localhost
      (?!)
 )

 # Folder/Parameters ------------
 (                                                     # (5 start)
      (?: : \d{2,5} )?
      (?: \/ [^\s]* )?
 )                                                     # (5 end)
 $
```